# Python, Pygame, Class object no longer callable

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a game using Pygame, now I am having this issue where I wanted to add a spawn timer on my monsters in the game. Now the timer works fine and the first spawn wave gets made and everything is great and terrific until the second wave where it says:

```
Monster1 = Monster()
```

> TypeError: 'Monster' object is not callable

Now this I don't get, since it already called it in the round before then.

I went over my text plenty of times just to see if I am changing any features in the the class or making it so that it shouldn't be callable anymore but I just don't get it.

This loop makes spawns the monsters

```
while Game:
    if time.clock() - WaveTimer > 10:
    WaveTimer = time.clock()
        print "The Moon is full"
        for i in range(3*SpawnRate):
            Monster1 = Monster()
            monster_list.add(Monster1)
            character_list.add(Monster1)
            SpawnRate += 1
```

This is the Monster class

```
class Monster(Character):
    Current_HP = 50
    Max_Hp = 50
    walking_frame = []
    fighting_frame = []
    hit_frame = []
    Fighting = False
    Flag = True
    frame1= 0
    LastFrame1 = 0
    TimeBetweenAtkFrames = 0.1
    X_Speed = 0
    Y_Speed = 0
    damaged = False
    RecordedAni = True
    damagedspeed = 1
    image_file = "C:/Users/Gideon/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Sprite Images/All.png"
    sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet(image_file)
    hitimage = sprite_sheet.get_image(96, 336, 48, 48)
    hitimage = pygame.transform.scale(hitimage, (50, 50))
    for i in range(5):
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(i * 48, 288, 48, 48)
        fighting_frame.append(image)
    for i in range(4):
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(i * 48, 144, 48, 48)  # Temp
        walking_frame.append(image)
    for i in range(4):
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(i * 48, 192, 48, 48)  # Temp
        walking_frame.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 144, 48, 48)
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, 50))
    orgimage = image
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.Loc_x = random.randrange(20,700)
        self.Loc_y = random.randrange(20,100)  # temp
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = [self.Loc_x, self.Loc_y]
        for i in range (2):
            image = self.sprite_sheet.get_image(i * 48, 336, 48, 48)
            self.hit_frame.append(image)
            i += 1
    def move(self,character):
        if self.Alive:
            if self.Current_HP < self.Max_Hp:
                self.damagedspeed = 2
            if character.Loc_x > self.Loc_x + 25:
                self.X_Speed = 1.5 * self.damagedspeed
                self.Loc_x += self.X_Speed
            if character.Loc_x < self.Loc_x - 25:
                self.X_Speed = 1.5 * self.damagedspeed
                self.Loc_x -= self.X_Speed
            if character.Loc_y > self.Loc_y + 25:
                self.Y_Speed = 1.5 * self.damagedspeed
                self.Loc_y += self.Y_Speed
            if character.Loc_y < self.Loc_y - 25:
                self.Y_Speed = 1.5 * self.damagedspeed
                self.Loc_y -= self.Y_Speed
            if (self.Flag):
                self.Animation()
            wall_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, CollideList, False)
            for wall in wall_hit_list:
                if self.X_Speed > 0:
                    self.X_Speed = 0
                    self.Loc_x = self.Loc_x - 5
                if self.X_Speed < 0:
                    self.X_Speed = 0
                    self.Loc_x = self.Loc_x + 5
                if self.Y_Speed > 0:
                    self.Y_Speed = 0
                    self.Loc_y = self.Loc_y - 5
                if self.Y_Speed < 0:
                    self.Y_Speed = 0
                    self.Loc_y = self.Loc_y + 5
            self.FightAnimation(character)
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orgimage, self.Angle)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.left, self.rect.top = [self.Loc_x, self.Loc_y]
            self.X_Speed = 0
            self.Y_Speed = 0
    def FightAnimation(self,character):
    #      Monster Fight Animation
        if character.Loc_x <= self.Loc_x + 25 and character.Loc_x >= self.Loc_x - 25:
            if character.Loc_y <= self.Loc_y + 25 and character.Loc_y >= self.Loc_y - 25:
                if(self.Fighting == False):
                    self.LastFrame1 = time.clock()
                    self.Fighting = True
                    if (self.frame1 < len(self.fighting_frame)):
                        self.Flag = False
                        self.image = self.fighting_frame[self.frame1]
                        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (60, 60))
                        self.orgimage = self.image
                        if (self.frame1 == 3):
                            character.Current_HP -= 20
                        self.frame1 += 1
                    else:
                        self.frame1 = 0
            else:
                if (self.frame1 != 0):
                    self.frame1 = 0
                self.Flag = True
        else:
            if (self.frame1 != 0):
                self.frame1 = 0
                self.image = self.fighting_frame[self.frame1]
                self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (60, 60))
                self.orgimage = self.image
            self.Flag = True
        if self.Fighting and time.clock() - self.LastFrame1 > self.TimeBetweenAtkFrames:
            self.Fighting = False
```

If there is anything else you'd need to know just tell me and I will add it
If this is really messy I am sorry its the first time I am using StackOverFlow website :$

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `Monster = something`, which shadows created class.

Comment: ^Thank you for the edits. I never used this site before. You are wonderful people

Comment: what @ŁukaszRogalski suggests is the most likely culprit. Following the 
[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding style will help you in this case as variable names are conventionally specified with lowercase letters, i.e. change instances like `Monster1=Monster()` to `monster1=Monster()`. You should be able to zero in on your problem quickly.

Comment: Thank you guys! You were right ! :) I found the problematic line and now its fixed.
@nluigi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you "overwrite" the name `Monster`, which then no longer points to your class.

Make sure you're not doing a `Monster = whatever` anywhere in your code.

Also, note that `Current_HP`, `Max_Hp` etc. are class members, not instance members, so if you chance `Current_HP` on a `Monster` instance, you change it for *all* `Monster` instances.

Comment: If I use something like Current_Hp or anything like that I do something in the lines of:    for bullet in bullet_list:
        monster_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet,monster_list,False)
        for monster in monster_hit_list:
            monster.Current_HP -= My_Man.Current_Weapon.Damage
            if monster.Current_HP <= 0:
                monster_list.remove(monster)
                character_list.remove(monster)
            bullet_list.remove (bullet)
            character_list.remove(bullet)
     Which seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found out the problematic line and now it works way better. thanks to you @sloth and thanks to everyone else!